# Black screen freeze after logging in Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, freeze, lts

I am using Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS on an Acer Aspire-5742G with Intel Core i3 processor, 8 GB RAM, 640 GB HDD and nVidia GeForce 520M with 1GB memory.

I ran BleachBit with `sudo` permissions form the terminal. In the GUI that opened I checked all of the features in the left panel of the program, except those for which the system said they would take a long time to perform. I noticed that it deleted some files from the system folders, but I ignored that. After that I did a

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and I rebooted my system.

Immediately after I logged in I got a black screen and the only thing I could do was to open a console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. I pressed Enter, it asked me for my log in credentials. Then I typed in `DISPLAY` and got the following error:

```
Cannot start X server - error/display.c/DisplayImageCommand/428
```

Please tell me what sequence of commands should I enter to fix this. If you need additional information, please ask. Although, I am still able to log in from the guest account.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a problem with your gpu-drivers. whats the errorcode if you type:

```
sudo startx
```

and the log from this:

```
more /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

and this:

```
lspci | grep VGA
```

Answer (score 0):

error written in .xsession-errors  in home folder can be helpful access it by pressing ctrl+alt+F1 and type your credentials 
 Right now i can only come up with two problem and their solution 
1) Permission of the file can be denied so make all files accessible to ubuntu so you will find the name of file in that error file and do

```
chmod 777 filename
```

or if you are lazy enough run these two command .

```
    chmod 777 .* 
    chmod 777 *
```

2) graphic driver might not be compatible
so

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it's not the nVidia driver what is causing this situation, because I did a couple of reboots after installing it. I think some critical system files have been blocked, modified or deleted by the BleachBit.

Comment: what's written in .xsession-errors ?

Comment: Never mind, I already did a clean sweep ...